# Add date time in filename

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to add datetime in my filename as shown below:
User_Call_Detail_20210406_20210407000004.csv
where 20210406 is the (current date - 1) and 20210407000004 is the current date with timestamp and User_Call_Detail is my filename.
I have written the code to add current date to the file name but i want to make the filename as shown above

```
counts.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").csv("User_Call_Detail"+currentdate+".csv")
```

Can anyone please help who have achieved this using Python?

Answer (score 0):

It easy enough with datetime strftime()

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
currTS = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

So, today that'd give you currTS = '20210407'

edit, OK, so looking previous day:

```
currTS = datetime.now()
prevTS = currTS - timedelta(days=1)
prevTS2 = prevTS.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Then to include the time:

```
currTS2 = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Which would give you '20210407143855'

Simply concatenate and your golden.

Comment: ya but i want to add previous date and then current date with timestamp in file name.

Comment: Ah, OK, will edit, previous day, or 24hrs previous?

Comment: I want to add previous day

Comment: getting error: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: In what line? All of those above do work, I've use them regularly. If you mean your line of syntax at the top of the thread, you need to take 2 minutes and look at how to write to files with python.